# How to output a utf-8 string list as it is in python?

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding

Well, character encoding and decoding sometimes frustrates me a lot.

So we know `u'\u4f60\u597d'` is the `utf-8` encoding of `你好`,

```
>>> print hellolist
[u'\u4f60\u597d']
>>> print hellolist[0]
你好
```

Now what I really want to get from the output or write to a file is `[u'你好']`, but it's `[u'\u4f60\u597d']` all the time, so how do you do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you print (or write to a file) a list it internally calls the `str()` method of the list , but list internally calls `repr()` on its elements. `repr()` returns the ugly unicode representation that you are seeing .

Example of repr -

```
>>> h = u'\u4f60\u597d'
>>> print h
\u4f60\u597d
>>> print repr(h)
u'\u4f60\u597d'
```

You would need to manually take the elements of the list and print them for them to print correctly.

Example -

```
>>> h1 = [h,u'\u4f77\u587f']
>>> print u'[' + u','.join([u"'" + unicode(i) + u"'" for i in h1]) + u']'
```

For lists containing sublists that may have unicode characters, you would need a recursive function , example -

```
>>> h1 = [h,(u'\u4f77\u587f',)]
>>> def listprinter(l):
...     if isinstance(l, list):
...             return u'[' + u','.join([listprinter(i) for i in l]) + u']'
...     elif isinstance(l, tuple):
...             return u'(' + u','.join([listprinter(i) for i in l]) + u')'
...     elif isinstance(l, (str, unicode)):
...             return u"'" + unicode(l) + u"'"
... 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> print listprinter(h1)
```

To save them to file, use the same list comprehension or recursive function. Example -

```
with open('<filename>','w') as f:
    f.write(listprinter(l))
```

Answer (score 5):

You are misunderstanding.

`u''` in python is *not* utf-8, it is simply Unicode (except on Windows in Python <= 3.2, where it is `utf-16` instead).

utf-8 is an *encoding* of Unicode, which is necessarily a sequence of `bytes`.

Additionally, `u'你'` and `u'\u4f60'` are exactly the same thing. It's simply that in Python2 the `repr` of high characters uses escapes instead of raw values.

Since Python2 is heading for EOL very soon now, you should start to think seriously about switching to Python3. It is a lot easier to keep track of all this in Python3 since there's only one string type and it's much more clear when you `.encode` and `.decode`.

Comment: Saying that `u''` is utf-16 on certain platforms and Python versions is irrelevant - it uses *some* encoding internally, but which one is an implementation detail (and you got the detail slightly wrong anyway: how unicode characters are represented internally used to depend on how the interpreter was compiled; it now depends on the characters in the string).  But +1 for `u'你'` and `u'\u4f60'` being the same thing, which is the important point here - these are different ways of printing the same object and the two spellings will be treated identically by Python in all situations.

Comment: @Ivc please do note, when you print the list , `u'\u4f60'` would be printed/converted as `u'\\u4f60` before printing or writing to file, this is the issue that the OP is talking about, this is because of the internal use of `repr()` by lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
 with open("some_file.txt","wb") as f:
    f.write(hellolist[0].encode("utf8"))
```

I think will resolve your issue

most text editors use utf8 encoding :)

while the other answers are correct none of them actually resolved your issue

```
>>> u'\u4f60\u597d'.encode("utf8")
'\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd'
```

if you want the brackets

```
>>> u'[u\u4f60\u597d,]'.encode("utf8")
```

Answer (score 0):

one thing is the unicode character itself

hellolist = u'\u4f60\'

and another is how you can represent it.

You can represent it in many many ways depending on where you are going to display.

Web: UTF-8
Database: maybe UTF-16 or UTF-8
Web in Japan: EUC-JP or Shift JIS

For example　本
http://unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=672c
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/672c/index.htm